# Panda 0.13.1 and Python 2.7.3

Tags: python

I am trying to download panda 0.13.1 in my python 2.7.3 for windows 7 and I get the following messages:

```
The process can not access the file because it is being used by another process.
CreateFile (C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pandas\algos.pyd)
CreateFile (C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pandas\hashtable.pyd)
CreateFile (C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pandas\index.pyd)
CreateFile (C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pandas\json.pyd)
```

Can I just create empty files as above and try to download again.
Also, how you create a file (with .pyd extension) in command line/shell.

Vigen

Comment: Reboot, looks like maybe the process is holding on to the files, then try again.

Comment: I have the same problem appearing.When I tried again, after exiting and then running the python, the process for some reason can not access the files, and I receive the same error messages.